# Retrieve Record Based on a Value Existing in Record's Association Table

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables. `posts` is the record I want, whilst `post_tags` allows a one-to-many relationship between them. NB. I have this working, however, they do not feel efficient to me and I could do with some SQLite gurus to help me out.

| posts |
| --- |
| id |

| post_tags |
| --- |
| post_id |
| tag |

## Exact Match

I want to be able to retrieve posts that match a specific tag that I pass in.

Here is my current query.

```sql
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE "desiredTag" IN (SELECT tag FROM post_tags WHERE post_id = posts.id AND tag = "desiredTag");
```

## One Of

My next requirement is an adaptation of the first. Instead of just matching one tag, I want to be able to pass in an array of `tags` and posts to be returned when they match at least one of the passed in tags. Again, I have this working but inefficiently.

```sql
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ("tagOne" IN (SELECT tag FROM post_tags WHERE post_id = posts.id AND tag = "tagOne") OR "tagTwo" IN (SELECT tag FROM post_tags WHERE post_id = posts.id AND tag = "tagTwo"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `EXISTS` performs better:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM posts p 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tag t WHERE t.post_id = p.id AND t.tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2'))
```

Or you could do it with an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*
FROM posts p INNER JOIN tag t
ON t.post_id = p.id 
WHERE t.tag IN ('tag1', 'tag2')
```